SQL Server TypeORM problem for other computer local network
So I want to connect to mssql server from my MAC in a NEST project. The SQL Server is running on windows machine on ip 192.168.31.78. I used DBEAVER in my mac which shows connection to be Successful. In my windows machine using localhost for DATABASE_HOST the app runs perfectly. what am I doing wrong.
DBEAVER working on MAC
sqlcmd can connect from mac
himanshupradhan@Himanshus-MacBook-Air ~ % sqlcmd -S 192.168.31.78,1433 -U himanshu
Password:
1> 

This is my env file in mac

----
NODE_ENV=development
APP_PORT=3005
DATABASE_TYPE=mssql
DATABASE_HOST=192.168.31.78
DATABASE_PORT=1433
DATABASE_USERNAME=himanshu
DATABASE_PASSWORD=****
DATABASE_NAME=****
DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE=false

-----

This is my config file:
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';

export type DatabaseConfig = {
  url: string;
  type: string;
  host: string;
  port: number;
  password: string;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  synchronize: boolean;
  maxConnections: number;
  sslEnabled: boolean;
  rejectUnauthorized: boolean;
  ca: string;
  key: string;
  cert: string;
};

export const databaseConfig = registerAs<Partial<DatabaseConfig>>(
  'database',
  () => ({
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    type: process.env.DATABASE_TYPE,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT || '3306', 10),
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    name: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    synchronize: process.env.DATABASE_SYNCHRONIZE === 'true',
    maxConnections: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_MAX_CONNECTIONS || '100', 10),
    sslEnabled: process.env.DATABASE_SSL_ENABLED === 'true',
    rejectUnauthorized: process.env.DATABASE_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED === 'true',
    ca: process.env.DATABASE_CA,
    key: process.env.DATABASE_KEY,
    cert: process.env.DATABASE_CERT,
  }),
);

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AllConfig } from '../config/config.type';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService<AllConfig>) {}

  createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
    return {
      type: this.configService.get('database.type', { infer: true }),
      url: this.configService.get('database.url', { infer: true }),
      host: this.configService.get('database.host', { infer: true }),
      port: this.configService.get('database.port', { infer: true }),
      username: this.configService.get('database.username', { infer: true }),
      password: this.configService.get('database.password', { infer: true }),
      database: this.configService.get('database.name', { infer: true }),
      synchronize: this.configService.get('database.synchronize', {
        infer: true,
      }),
      dropSchema: false,
      keepConnectionAlive: true,
      logging: false,
      entities: [__dirname + '/../../**/*.mssql-entity{.ts,.js}'],
      // autoLoadEntities: true,
      migrations: [__dirname + '/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
      cli: {
        entitiesDir: 'src',
        migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
        subscribersDir: 'subscriber',
      },
      options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
      },
      extra: {
        // based on https://node-postgres.com/apis/pool
        // max connection pool size
        max: this.configService.get('database.maxConnections', { infer: true }),
        ssl: this.configService.get('database.sslEnabled', { infer: true })
          ? {
              rejectUnauthorized: this.configService.get(
                'database.rejectUnauthorized',
                { infer: true },
              ),
              ca:
                this.configService.get('database.ca', { infer: true }) ??
                undefined,
              key:
                this.configService.get('database.key', { infer: true }) ??
                undefined,
              cert:
                this.configService.get('database.cert', { infer: true }) ??
                undefined,
            }
          : undefined,
      },
    } as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
  }
}

The error I'm getting is:
[Nest] 45742  - 10/07/2024, 4:03:27 PM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 192.168.31.78:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
    at connectListener (/Users/himanshupradhan/coding/IOE_EMIS/ioe-result-system-backend-nestjs/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/connection-pool.js:85:17)
    at Connection.onConnect (/Users/himanshupradhan/coding/IOE_EMIS/ioe-result-system-backend-nestjs/node_modules/tedious/src/connection.ts:1759:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at Connection.emit (/Users/himanshupradhan/coding/IOE_EMIS/ioe-result-system-backend-nestjs/node_modules/tedious/src/connection.ts:1902:18)
    at Connection.socketError (/Users/himanshupradhan/coding/IOE_EMIS/ioe-result-system-backend-nestjs/node_modules/tedious/src/connection.ts:2309:12)
    at /Users/himanshupradhan/coding/IOE_EMIS/ioe-result-system-backend-nestjs/node_modules/tedious/src/connection.ts:2098:37
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

I tried 192.168.31.78\SQLEXPRESS and 192.168.31.78\SQLEXPRESS both saying connection timedout
